# How to connect my app on Heroku to my database in Atlas with an IP whitelist?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I'm connecting my Node.js app deployed on Heroku with my MongoDB hosted in Atlas but I don't want to allow connections from anywhere (0.0.0.0).

Heroku doesn't give me a consistent IP address, so I can't whitelist my app.

I need a way to connect to the database in Atlas but with control. How can I allow my app on Heroku to connect without opening my database up to the world?

Comment: Did you try Fixie Socks ? Can you share how you got it to work ? I added Fixie Socks to my project, but I'm not sure how to configure it or what to change in my node express app to use it correctly.

Comment: well it's no longer needed since i'm not working on that project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku itself [doesn't really do this](https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-whitelist-heroku-dynos-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku), but if you use a [networking addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/categories/network) like [Fixie Socks](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie-socks) or [Fixie](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie) you can get a static outbound IP address.